# Object exist BUT trying to get property on a non object

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

Im working on a project on Laravel5 with PHP 5.5.12 and MYSQL 5.6.17
yesterday everything was working fine, but when i come back to my code today,
i have the error "Trying to get property of non-object" on multiple models objects, the case occurs often when they have relationships with other models.

if i write this :

```
$test = $model->relation->property;
```

I get the error.

If i write this :

```
echo / var_dump($model->relation->property);
```

then its printed with no problem.

I really don't know what happen and any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Ps: sorry if im wrong about the text i wrote, its the first time i ask question on stackoverflow :)
Oh and i did already read all similar questions

This is Stay.php model :

```
namespace App\models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Stay extends CustomModel {

protected $table = 'stay';

protected $fillable = array('reservation_terms_convention_id', 'reservation_id', 'period_id', 'total_price', 'price_ht', 'occupant_id', 'prestation_fixe_id', 'pax', 'checkin', 'checkout');

protected $guarded = array('id');

static public $mailTemplatingWhitelist = ['total_price'];

public static $rules = [
'reservation_terms_convention_id' => 'required|exists:reservation_terms_convention,id',
'period_id' => 'required|exists:period,id',
'payeur_id' => 'required'
];


    public function payment_due_date()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\models\PaymentDueDate','payment_due_date_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

here is the related model :

```
<?php namespace App\models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PaymentDueDate extends CustomModel {


protected $table = 'payment_due_date';

protected $fillable = array('total_amount', 'acompte_amount', 'amount_ht', 'amount_already_payed', 'payment_total_date', 'payment_acompte_date',
        'facturation_date', 'description_facture', 'type', 'cash_desk_id', 'individual_customer_id',
        'partner_id', 'direction');

protected $guarded = array('id');


public function stay(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\models\Stay');
}

}
```

And finally the controller :

```
public function print_partner_invoice($partner_id, $echeance = 0)

    $partner = Partner::find($partner_id);

    // this return Collection of model
    $partner_resa = Partner::reservations_echeance($partner->id, $echeance);

    if(!$partner || $partner_resa->count() < 1)
        abort(403);



    $residence_company = $partner_resa->first()->residence->residence_company;

    $total_ttc = 0;
    $already_paid = 0;
    $tva_amount = 0;


    foreach ($partner_resa as $key => $resa) {

        foreach ($resa->stays as $key => $stay) {
            $amount = $stay->payment_due_date->total_amount;
        }

    }

    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('reglement.partner_invoice', [
        'partner'               => $partner,
        'resas'                 => $partner_resa,
        'residence_company'     => $residence_company,
        'total_ttc'             => $total_ttc,
        'already_paid'          => $already_paid,
        'tva_amount'            => $tva_amount
        ]);

    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error? You should have filename and line number in the error message

Comment: How does var_dump output looks like

Comment: ErrorException in ReglementController.php line 99:
    Trying to get property of non-object in ReglementController.php line 99

This line produce the bug :

 $amount = $stay->payment_due_date->total_amount;

If i write var_dump($stay->payment_due_date->total_amount)
i have no error

Answer (score 0):

First, if you write

```
var_dump($doesnotexists1->doesnotexists2->doesnotexists3);
```

its null, there will be no error, because var_dump looks for $doesnotexists1, and if its null it will not looking further. So you get no "Trying to get property of non-object in " Execption.

So, your problem is maybe that $stay or $stay->payment_due_date at

```
 $amount = $stay->payment_due_date->total_amount;
```

is null/empty.

i Would check it like

```
foreach ($partner_resa as $key => $resa) {

    foreach ($resa->stays as $key => $stay) {
      if(is_object(stay) && is_object($stay->payment_due_date)) {
        $amount = $stay->payment_due_date->total_amount;
      }
    }
}
```

to get sure that it is a object

Comment: no. there will be notice `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: doesnotexists1 in xxx on line YYY`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski,  Sorry, I did not know that there will be a Notice, thanks